# Trim all characters except numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get the percentage from two numbers. If you loook at the fiddle it works with the first number. For the second numbers I need to trim the first number a bit more, but unsure how.

The first number works.

The second number needs a regex that removes spaces and characters after the numbers.

The third one needs a regex that removes the comma in between numbers , and all characters after the dot.

The fourth one needs a regex that removes the characters before the numbers, the comma between numbers and the dot and all characters behind

How do I write it so it works in all cases? Whatever I try just brakes one or the others.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/5/

Script:

```
$('.left').each(function() {
var frstCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price').text().trim().replace(/[€\.]/g, ''), 10);
var seCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price.before').text().trim(), 10);        
var result = (frstCol / seCol) * 100;
$(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(parseInt(result)|| 0);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    €1.019&nbsp; // should count as 1019
    <span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span>
 </em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">
    1519
 </em>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
</div>

<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    5&nbsp;995:-&nbsp; // should count as 5995
    <span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span>
 </em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">
    987
 </em>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
</div>

<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    11,823.00SEK&nbsp; // should count as 1183
    <span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span>
 </em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">
    1987
 </em>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
</div>

<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    SEK11,823.00&nbsp; // should count as 1183
    <span class="vatstatus">Exclusief BTW</span>
 </em>
 <em class="price product-card-price before">
    1987
 </em>
 <a class="pricebubble"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Which of the vars are you trying to filter?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all but numeric characters

```
str.replace(new RegExp("[^0-9.]","gm"),"your string");
```

Suppose you have this string:

```
var str ="dsfdsf7834hf3876gfergh"
```

Then, `str.replace(new RegExp("[^0-9.]","gm"),"foo");`
will return `"foofoofoofoofoofoo7834foofoo3876foofoofoofoofoofoo"`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
str.replace(/[\D]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: (https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/6/)

```
$('.left').each(function() {
    var frstCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "").replace(/\.[0-9]*/, ""), 10);
    var seCol = parseInt($(this).find('em.price.product-card-price.before').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""), 10);        
    var result = (frstCol / seCol) * 100;
    console.log("frstCol: ", frstCol, ", seCol: ", seCol);
   $(this).find('a.pricebubble').text(parseInt(result)|| 0);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Luc this works fot he last two numbers, but not the first ones: https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/7/ (changed the results to show the negative number)

Comment: It depends on your delimiter. I just thought 1.019 is 1, not 1019 :D Any way, remove this `.replace(/\.[0-9]*/, "")`, you will get 1019

Comment: Hi @Luc, i tried this in your and mine fiddle, doesn't seems to work?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: if you look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/9/ you can see that the last two numbers shows 33% - this is correct. The two above number has the same numbers, and should also show 33, but they are broken.

Comment: the number was a bit of, here is the correct: https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/10/. Now all should show 33 when the regex is correct.

Comment: The second number works if i add two decimals (.00) for some reason, not sure why.

Comment: this is the closest I got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/14/ If i add .00 decimals to the first two numbers they have the correct output, so the error lies with the regex for removing those on the other numbers I Guess.